# Can't run CS50 command in VisualStudio code Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cs50, powershell-cmdlet

Commands of CS50 are no more working anymore. I tried to redo steps of configuring SSH following the link https://cs50.readthedocs.io/github/#ssh , but I'm facing the message error present in the image below : [CS50 command image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFc7n.png)

Answer (score 0):

After checking the documentation you provided and assuming it's what you followed,
https://cs50.readthedocs.io/projects/check50/en/latest/ states "Under Windows, please install the Linux subsystem. Then install check50 within the subsystem."

But in your picture you are using PowerShell (PS) so you can either start wsl from it by using the command `wsl` or you can open a new terminal from the vscode gui but make sure you selected wsl this time !